# Continuous functions unbounded on set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

For Each of the sets construct a continuous function that is unbounded on the set.

1. $\Bbb N$
2. $(2,3)$
3. $\left\{\frac 1 n \mid n \in \Bbb N\right\}$
4. $[0, \sqrt 2]\cap \Bbb Q$
5. $[2,7]\setminus\bigl\{\sqrt5\bigr\}$

Guess: 
For something like Natural Numbers, would F(x) = x be okay? I know it is continuous, but I don't understand if it is unbounded on the set.

For something like (4) or (5) I am absolutely clueless.

Comment: A function is said to be unbounded if for any $M$, there is an $N$ so that $n > N \rightarrow f(n) > f(M),$ so it suffices to find a function which diverges to infinity in each of those sets.

Comment: So something l/(x-2)(x-3) would be unbounded for (2,3)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  The tricky point is that that same solution would not work for $[2,3]$, since the function is actually *undefined* at 2 and at 3, so if you say $1/(x-2)(x-3)$ you have not actually given a function with the required domain. Fortunately the question asks for a function unbounded not on $[2,3]$ but on $(2,3)$, for which your answer works. (In fact, there is no continuous unbounded function defined everywhere on $[2,3]$).  I bring this up because you will need a different kind of trick to deal with item (5).

Comment: What kind of trick?

Comment: It needs to be bounded at the endpoints, and unbounded in the vicinity of $\sqrt 5$.

Comment: So Something like 1/(x-square root of 5) would work because it includes the endpoints, but does not include the square root of five correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  And you can use a similar function for item (4).

Comment: Even Though in number 4 it includes the rationals? So really number 4 can be rewritten as [0,square root of 2) because square root of 2 is irrational

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use functions of the form $ {1 \over x - a}$. This function is continuous except at $x = a$, and is unbounded in any interval containing $a$.